# IModelBinder not firing on MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, model-binding

I have this Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Execute(PaymentModel paymentModel){...}
```

this is the model

```
public class PaymentModel
{
[Required]
[DisplayName("Full name")]
public string FullName { get; set; }
...
}
```

this is the binding action

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PaymentModel), new PaymentModelsBinding());           
        }
```

this is the binding inplementation

```
public class PaymentModelsBinding : IModelBinder
    {
        public  object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
//Cant get to here with the debugger
}
```

I dont know if that is relevant or not, but I am injecting using Ninject to the controller constructor.

**Update**
This is how the form is submitted:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $("#form").attr("action"),
                data: $("#form").serialize(),
                success: function (json) {
                    ...

                },
                dataType: "Json"
            });
```

I want that to be restful, meaning I will to call it in every possible WEB way.
Browser Ajax, Browser Classic form submission, WebClient... and more.

**Update**
This is my ninject code:

```
kernel.Components.Add<IInjectionHeuristic, CustomInjectionHeuristic>();


            kernel.Bind<IPaymentMethodFactory>().ToProvider<PaymentMethodFactoryProvider>().InSingletonScope();
            kernel.Bind<IDefaultBll>().To<DefaultBll>().InSingletonScope();

            kernel
                .Bind<IDalSession>()
                .ToProvider<HttpDalSessionProvider>()
                .InRequestScope();
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling this controller action? The model binder will be called when the action is invoked.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov -  I am calling that via a web form.
I am able to invoke `Execute(PaymentModel paymentModel)` but not the model before it.

Comment: Could you show how are you calling it? Do you have some HTML form inside the view which gets submitted? Or are you using AJAX? Or some other way to call this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I can't see anything wrong with your code. This should work. And as a proof of concept, here's what you could try:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the Internet Template
2. Define a view model:

   ```
       public class PaymentModel
       {
           [Required]
           [DisplayName("Full name")]
           public string FullName { get; set; }
       }
   ```
3. A custom model binder:

   ```
   public class PaymentModelsBinding : IModelBinder
   {
       public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {
           return new PaymentModel();
       }
   }
   ```
4. HomeController:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View(new PaymentModel());
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Index(PaymentModel model)
       {
           return Json(new { success = true });
       }
   }
   ```
5. A corresponding view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

   ```
   @model PaymentModel

   @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
   {
       @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FullName)
       <button type="submit">OK</button>
   }

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#form').submit(function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: this.method,
               url: this.action,
               data: $(this).serialize(),
               success: function (json) {

               }
           });
           return false;
       });
   </script>
   ```
6. And finally register the model binder in `Application_Start`:

   ```
   ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PaymentModel), new PaymentModelsBinding());
   ```
7. Run the application in Debug mode, submit the form and the custom model binder gets hit.

So the question now becomes: what did you do differently?

Comment: I just did and it is working. Can it be the ninject? I edit my post and added it at the bottom

Comment: @SexyMF, yes many things could cause that. Unfortunately I am not an oracle and cannot remotely read or understand what code you could have hypothetically written. But it is unlikely that this is caused by NInject. I would recommend you to start eliminating the causes. Start from a working state (see my answer) and then progressively start adding stuff until your code stops working. Now you will have isolated the problem and would have found the smoking gun. Good luck.